# Unable to find data while web-scraping a tournment sign up website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to scrape tournament information from https://pickleballbrackets.com/pts.aspx. The site hosts tournament information for pickleball tournaments around the world. I'm not a fan of the site and thought scraping the data into a spreadsheet would be much easier to deal with. I'm using requests, beautifulsoup, and pandas. When inspecting the page for data, it seems they have it hidden. See attached screenshot. Any assistance with coding for this would be great. I'm fairly new to this, so apologies in advance. I've messed with different ways to find the data (p tags, body tags).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Make a request to the website
r = requests.get('https://pickleballbrackets.com/pts.aspx')

# Parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

# Find the data you want to extract. For example, let's say we want to extract all the text within <p> tags.
body_tags = soup.find_all('body')

# Extract the text from each tag and store it in a list
data = [tag.text for tag in body_tags]

# Convert the list into a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Text'])

# Save the DataFrame to a CSV file
df.to_csv('scraped_data.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you see on the page is loaded from external URL via JavaScript. You can simulate this with `requests` module, e.g.:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = "https://pickleballbrackets.com/Json.asmx/EventsSearch_PublicUI"
payload = {
    "AgeIDs": "",
    "Alpha": "All",
    "ClubID": "",
    "CountryID": "",
    "DateFilter": "future",
    "EventTypeIDs": "1",
    "FormatIDs": "",
    "FromDate": "",
    "IncludeTestEvents": "0",
    "OrderBy": "EventActivityFirstDate",
    "OrderDirection": "Asc",
    "PageNumber": "2",
    "PageSize": 50,
    "PlayerGroupIDs": "",
    "PrizeMoney": "All",
    "prt": "",
    "RankIDs": "",
    "ReturnType": "json",
    "SearchWord": "",
    "ShowOnCalendar": "0",
    "SportIDs": "dc1894c6-7e85-43bc-bfa2-3993b0dd630f",
    "StateIDs": "",
    "ToDate": ""
}


all_dfs = []
for payload['PageNumber'] in range(1, 3):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload).json()
    #print(data)
    all_dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(data['d']))

df = pd.concat(all_dfs)

# print some example columns
print(df[['Title', 'Registration_DateOpen', 'LocationOfEvent_Venue', 'Cost_Registration_Current']])
```

Prints:

| Title | Registration_DateOpen | LocationOfEvent_Venue | Cost_Registration_Current |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Midnight Pickleball Heist Series | 5/15/2023 8:00:00 AM | Little Valley Pickleball Complex | 40 |
| Northeast Winter Open by Montclair Pickleball | 6/5/2023 5:00:00 PM | Randolph Pickleball Center | 60 |
| Grand Rapids BEER CITY OPEN Pickleball Championships | 5/10/2023 10:00:00 AM | Belknap Park in Grand Rapids, MI | 90 |
| 2023 Humana Seattle Metro Classic | 4/7/2023 8:00:00 AM | Shoreview Park | 65 |
| Lakeside 2023 Pickleball Tournament | 6/20/2023 8:00:00 AM | Hubbard Pickleball Center | 15 |
| Fall Classic - Life Time Troy | 7/16/2023 8:00:00 AM | Troy Life Time | 30 |
| 002 Pitch Cup 5 (Mens Doubles 3.5) | 1/8/2023 8:00:00 AM | The Pitch in Austin | 30 |
| Rocky Mountain State Games by PIG | 3/1/2023 8:00:00 AM | Monument Valley Park | 50 |
| The Preserve Pickleball Tournament | 5/1/2023 9:30:00 AM | THE PRESERVE PICKLEBALL | 30 |

...

Comment: That's phenomenal. Thank you so much. For the column headings, where did you get  those headings? @Andrej-Kesely

Comment: @testnameignore I've found the url in web developer tools (Chrome/Firefox have it) -> Network tab. Just open the tools and reload the page, you should see the url there.